# Applescript applicationH

Tags: applescript

I've made my first apple script (with a bit of help).
It works fine:

```
delay 5
tell application "SelfControl"
    activate
end tell


tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SelfControl"

        click button "Start" of window 1

    end tell
end tell
```

This was running inside applescript. Now I'm trying to run it as an application, So I've added the line

```
on run {input, parameters}
```

[at the top]

and the lines

```
return input
end run
```

[at the bottom]

and then exported as an application. however I get the error
"current application doesn’t match the parameters {input, parameters} for run." when I try to run.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

What use do you have of these parameters in your code?
How are you going to give them as an input and receive the output?

When I exported AppleScript codes as applications, I didn't add these lines and they worked completely fine. Just try to export without them!

Comment: Yes. I don't know why I added this, thanks. It works fine without. haha.

Answer (score 0):

The `on run` handler **with** parameters belongs to the Automator AppleScript action.

Every script / application script provides an implicit `on run` handler (**without** parameters) and without `return` value.

```
on run 

...

end run
```

This handler is only needed explicitly if other basic handlers like `on idle` or `on open` are specified, too. In all other cases just omit it.